# Как сделать регулярку, чтобы удалялся последний ноль в десятичной дроби

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеем - `pattern = '/\b.[0]+[0][\d]*/'` пользуюсь функцией `preg_replace`

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать регулярку, чтобы удалялся последний `0` в десятичной дроби перед цифрой.

Пример: `07.10 => 07.1` (требуемый результат)

Comment: менять `0+$` на пустую строку, если вы уже точно знаете, что там десятичная дробь с точкой. А если нет, то опишите задачу подробнее. И кстати, какое отношение вопрос имеет к MySQL (который вы указали в тегах) ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 0):

http://ideone.com/5SRtWf

```
echo preg_replace('/0$/', '', '07.10');
echo "\n";

echo preg_replace('/(\..*)0$/', '$1', '07.10');
echo "\n";

echo preg_replace('/(\..*)0$/', '$1', '0710');
echo "\n";
```

По необходимости поменять `0$` на `0+$`.

Comment: Это `echo preg_replace('/(\..*)0$/', '$1', '0710');` не нужно автору, там нет дробной части.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, так оно и не заменяется в этом случае.

Comment: извини не обратил внимания)))

Comment: А вы считаете правильным что регулярка берет и эту строку '0.7sd1090'

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, я сделал логичное предположение, что строка содержит число. Отделить целое число от дробного - логично. Отделять же мусор от числа без явного на то требования - на мой взгляд - нет. Так что да, я считаю это нормальным.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример работающей регулярки:

**(\.)([0-9]+)0$**

Это пример кода работы регулярки:

```
<?php

$pattern = '#(\.)([0-9]+)0$#';

$str1 = '0.71090';
$str2 = '104.01540';
$str3 = '1.203';

echo $str1.' - ';echo preg_replace($pattern, '$1$2', $str1);
echo '<br>';
echo $str2.' - ';echo preg_replace($pattern, '$1$2', $str2);

echo '<br>';
echo $str3.' - ';echo preg_replace($pattern, '$1$2', $str3);

?>
```

А это ответ выведенный в экран браузера после выполнения кода выше:

**0.71090 - 0.7109**

**104.01540 - 104.0154**

**1.203 - 1.203**

Comment: Наверное, неверно на `1.203`?

Comment: @Qwertiy баг, исправлю)

Comment: Приветствую Вас! У Qwerty  Пример кода предыдущий убирает все нули до 0.1

Comment: У Qwerty последний Пример кода - выдает ошибку

Comment: @Serhiy можете и на его ответ сделать комментарии

Comment: Однако хочу вас поблагодарить за Ваши отзывы и интересные идеи. Буду самостоятельно добивать свою регулярку.

Comment: @Serhiy Интересно только мое предложение каким вашим критериям не соответствовал ?

Comment: Razmik! Вам отдельное почтение и уважение, Вы победитель среди профессионалов. И наверно отличный  Руководитель..Я охотно воспользуюсь вашими советами по мат. части Регулярных выражений по указанной тематике!.

Comment: @Serhiy, какую ещё ошибку? [Нет ошибок.](http://ideone.com/Mg0s96) И я не Qwerty.